# Mimic linux openssl command in C#

Tags: c#, linux, openssl

I have a linux command and I'm trying to figure out how to mimic it in C# to get what is expected but can't seem to get it. It has to do with hashing a url with a secret key. The linux command is (fake site and numbers just for example):

```
echo -n "http://example.com/deliver?id=8247653546577888776655553d323453-3h78-7y42-b3d7-8u4q111y5hr6&timestamp=1556034591" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "567gy324-6666-4444-fr46-2h7arwdh5555"
```

I don't really know what the commands mean so not sure where to even start with how to try and get this kind of call in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This OpenSSL command is calculating an HMAC of the data passed to it on stdin (i.e. the output from the echo command). HMAC is a type of Message Authentication Code (MAC) and is used to verify the integrity of the message, i.e. if an attacker were to modify the message in any way then the MAC code would no longer match (it would fail to verify). HMAC combines a key with an underlying hash algorithm (SHA1 in this case) to generate the output MAC value.

The Microsoft docs provide a full example of how to perform an HMAC with SHA1 operation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1?view=netframework-4.8